# ToolBar is Empty & inactive

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

Using this Code,

Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

ActionBarActivity :

```
    final Toolbar ToolB = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(ToolB);
    ToolB.setTitle("ToolBar Test");
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The Output is just a blue empty rectangle, it does not react to Touch Event, it's like a Picture.   I also get a Menu by pressing The Menu Button (which is working), but there is no Three Dots at top right, nothing.

What am I missing or have got wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to the previous activity when press the home button you have to override the method "onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)" on the activity. Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For the settings button (those three dots) you have to create a menu (file) like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
         android:id="@+id/action_settings"
         android:orderInCategory="100"
         android:title="@string/action_settings"
         app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

and inflate it on the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I hope these examples to help you.

Comment: Thanks but this is Not what i was looking for, i Fixed my Problem, that's because i have a kind of Splash Screen & the Code was Not Executed in the refreshed View